# Can't position items how I want it

Tags: html, css

My "Products" bar isn't where is supposed to be. I am trying to put it near my sidebar in left. I don't want so much distance.

I have "float:left". I can't move it to the left using margin-left or right.

If I have "float:right", I can do this, but I don't want that.

I want to set it with "float:left" option.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUd8E.png)

tast.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- START HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>xPeke</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->

<!-- START BODY -->
<body>
<div class="content">

<!-- START TOPBAR -->
    <div id="program">
        <b style="color:black;">Program:</b> Luni-Vineri: 9:00-22:00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Sambata: 9:00–20:00 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Duminica: Inchis
                <a href="#" style="float:right">Login <span> / </span> Register</a>
    </div><br>
<!-- END TOPBAR -->

<!-- START SLIDESHOW -->    
    <div class="slideshow-container">
            <img class="mySlides" src="images/logo1.png" alt="Logo1" width="1500" height="300">
            <img class="mySlides" src="images/logo2.png" alt="Logo2" width="1500" height="300">
            <img class="mySlides" src="images/logo3.png" alt="Logo3" width="1500" height="300">
                <div class="butonpoza">
                    <button onclick="clearTimeout(timer)">Opreste Animatia</button>
                        <div class="dotts">
                            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                        </div>
                </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a><br>
    </div>
<!-- END SLIDESHOW -->

<!-- START LOGO, SEARCH & SOCIAL BAR -->
    <div>
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="180" height="45" style="float:left">
        <input class="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    <div style="float:right">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img class="socialmedia" src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img class="socialmedia" src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"></a>
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/"><img class="socialmedia" src="images/reddit.png" alt="Reddit"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- END LOGO, SEARCH & SOCIAL BAR -->

<!-- START NAVIGATION BAR -->
    <div style="float:left"><br>
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="active" href="#home">Produse</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Laptop, Telefoane & Tablete</a>
                    <a href="#">Televizoare & Desktop</a>
                    <a href="#">Tehnologii Smart</a>
                    <a href="#">Haine & Accesorii</a>
                    <a href="#">Anime & Manga</a>
                    <a href="#">Carti de Joc</a>
                    <a href="#">Jocuri & Jucarii</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#news">Articole</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Promotii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Wishlist</a></li>
            <li><a href="#daaaa">FAQ</a></li>
            <li style="padding: 0px 432.5px;"></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a href="#daaaa">Cosul meu</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a href="#daaaa">Contul meu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- END NAVIGATION BAR -->

<!-- START SIDEBAR -->
    <div style="float:left"><br>
        <a href="#" class="da">Noutati</a>
        <a href="#" class="da">Cele mai populare</a>
        <a href="#" class="da">Cele mai vandute</a>
        <a href="#" class="da">Precomenzi</a>
        <a href="#" class="da">Oferte speciale</a>
        <h3>Anunturi</h3>
        <aside class="sidebar"> 
            <section class="articles">
                <article class="article clearfix">
                    <img class="article__image" src="images/art1.png" alt="Hello World!">
                    <div class="article__content">
                        <h3 class="article__title">Hello Everyone!</h3>
                        <p class="pby">posted by xPeke</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="article clearfix">
                    <img class="article__image" src="images/art2.png" alt="Yu-Gi-Oh!">
                    <div class="article__content">
                        <h3 class="article__title">We've added the newest Yu-Gi-Oh cards.</h3>
                        <p class="pby">posted by Rekkles</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="article clearfix">
                    <img class="article__image" src="images/art3.png" alt="iPhone">
                    <div class="article__content">
                        <h3 class="article__title">A aparut noul iphone 8.</h3>
                        <p class="pby">posted by Soaz</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>
        </aside>
        <form class="twentyone">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Newsletter</legend><br>
                <div>
                    Daca vrei sa afli ultimele promotii si noutați aboneaza-te la newsletter-ul Fnatic!
                </div><br>
                <div>
                    <input class="newslt" type="text" name="newslt" placeholder="Email">
                </div><br>
                <div>
                    <button class="fltrgt" type="submit">Aboneaza-te!</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form><br>
    </div>
<!-- END SIDEBAR -->

<!-- START PRODUSE RECOMANDATE BAR -->
    <div class="prodrec">
        <h2> Products </h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="1" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="2" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="3" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <!-- Spatiu-->
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><br></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- pana aici-->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="4" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="5" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="6" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Spatiu-->
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><br></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- pana aici-->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="7" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="8" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="9" class="items">
                        <img src="img/products/robot1.jpg"/>
                        <span class="desc">Description</span>
                        <span class="price">$100</span>
                        <span class="other">Other</span>
                        <button>BUY</button>      
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Spatiu-->
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><br></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- pana aici-->
        </table>
    </div>
<!-- END PRODUSE RECOMANDATE BAR -->

    <div style="float:right">
        <h1> RIGHT! </h1>
    </div>

<!-- START SCRIPT ZONE -->  
    <script>
        var slideIndex = 1;
        var timer = null;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
            if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
            if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";       
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 10000);
        }   
    </script>
<!-- END SCRIPT ZONE -->

<!-- START FOOTER -->   
    <footer style="float:left">
        <div class="skills">&copy; Cat e facut din site pana acum: 60%</div>
    </footer>
<!-- END FOOTER -->
</div>
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->

</html>
```

test.css

```
.prodrec{
    float: left;

}



/* START BODY */
body{
    background-image: url("images/bgd.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
.content {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* END BODY */

/* START TOPBAR */
#program{
    font-size: 90%;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #2E2EFE;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
a{
    color: #2E2EFE;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}
/* END TOPBAR */

/* START SLIDESHOW */
.slideshow-container{
    position: relative;
}
.mySlides{
    display:none;
    width:100%;
}
.butonpoza{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position:relative;
}
/* END SLIDESHOW */

/* START SAGETI */
.prev, .next{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.next{
    width: 15px;
    right: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
/* END SAGETI */

/* START DOTTS */
.dot{
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .dot:hover{
    background-color: white;
}
.dotts{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -1362px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
/* END DOTTS */

/* START SEARCH AND SOCIAL BAR */
.search{
    width: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("images/search.png");
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 32px;
    width: 69%; 
}
.socialmedia{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
/* END SEARCH AND SOCIAL BAR */

/* START NAVIGATION BAR */
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li{
    float: left;
}
li a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active){
    background-color: #111;
}
.dropdown{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn{
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.active{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a{
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover:not(.active){
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: block;
}
/* END NAVIGATION BAR */

/* START SIDEBAR */
.da{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
.da:hover:not(.active){
    background-color: #fb2545;
}
.sidebar{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar .article__image{
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
}
.sidebar .article__content{
    float: right;
    width: 61%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.sidebar .article__title{
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-family: 'Oswald' !important;
}
.pby{
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
    color: #995d08;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.clearfix::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.twentyone{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}
.newslt{
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("images/email.png");
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;    
}
.fltrgt{
    float: right;
}
/* END SIDEBAR */

/* START PRODUSE RECOMANDATE BAR */
tr{
    display: block;
}
td{
    display: inline-block;
}
.items{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0 7px 0 7px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.items img{
    width: 160px;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(207, 207, 207, .7);
}
.items button{
    background: #666;
    width: 80px;
    height: 26px;
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
}
.items button:hover{
    background: #888;

}
.desc, .price, .other{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* END PRODUSE RECOMANDATE BAR */

/* START FOOTER */
footer{
    height: 40px;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
.skills{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
}
/* END FOOTER */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using bootstrap to create your layout? It makes things like this really easy.

Check it out here : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

You can use `pull-right` and `pull-left` within your columns to align your content and `text-right` and `text-left` for text.

I believe `pull-right` and `pull-left` have been replaced with `float-right` and `float-left` in Bootstrap 4.

Have fun experimenting with bootstrap!

This site lets you play around with your layouts also http://www.bootply.com

Comment: Bootstrap makes styling a breeze! Some great functionality with JS as well!

Comment: Have you tried setting a width in percentage for each sidebar to equal the max-width:1500px; to try to make up the gap in floats. Also have you tried using position?
May I ask why you do not wish to go with float:right to achieve desired effect?

Comment: @dalelandry It worked with float:left and margin-left now. I dont know, I just wanted to try harder with float:left.

Comment: @Mocanu Cristian glad it is working for you. Bootstrap is great, you can always overwrite css locally if needed. The functionality is well worth the price you pay in styling, which styling can often be a developers worst nightmare, KISS is the way to go and Bootstrap is elegant and simple in its design!

Comment: Glad it works. Completely agree with @dalelandry here. I was introduced to bootstrap a few years ago and I've never looked back.